# Best way to detect similar email addresses?

Tags: c#, levenshtein-distance

I have a list of ~20,000 email addresses, some of which I know to be fraudulent attempts to get around a "1 per e-mail" limit, such as username1@gmail.com, username1a@gmail.com, username1b@gmail.com, etc. I want to find similar email addresses for evaluation. Currently I'm using a Levenshtein algorithm to check each e-mail against the others in the list and report any with an edit distance of less than 2. However, this is painstakingly slow. Is there a more efficient approach?

The test code I'm using now is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace LevenshteinAnalyzer
{
    class Program
    {
        const string INPUT_FILE = @"C:\Input.txt";
        const string OUTPUT_FILE = @"C:\Output.txt";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var inputWords = File.ReadAllLines(INPUT_FILE);
            var outputWords = new SortedSet<string>();

            for (var i = 0; i < inputWords.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i % 100 == 0) 
                    Console.WriteLine("Processing record #" + i);

                var word1 = inputWords[i].ToLower();
                for (var n = i + 1; n < inputWords.Length; n++)
                {
                    if (i == n) continue;
                    var word2 = inputWords[n].ToLower();

                    if (word1 == word2) continue;
                    if (outputWords.Contains(word1)) continue;
                    if (outputWords.Contains(word2)) continue;
                    var distance = LevenshteinAlgorithm.Compute(word1, word2);

                    if (distance <= 2)
                    {
                        outputWords.Add(word1);
                        outputWords.Add(word2);
                    }
                }
            }

            File.WriteAllLines(OUTPUT_FILE, outputWords.ToArray());
            Console.WriteLine("Found {0} words", outputWords.Count);
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Some of the stuff I'm trying to catch looks like:

01234567890@gmail.com
0123456789@gmail.com
012345678@gmail.com
01234567@gmail.com
0123456@gmail.com
012345@gmail.com
01234@gmail.com
0123@gmail.com
012@gmail.com

Comment: What happens when you have two similar emails that belong to two different people?

Comment: That's why I'm providing the list to a human for evaluation purposes after...

Comment: If you run the code only when people try to make a new account, then it will cost you `O(n)` as opposed to `O(n^2)`.

Comment: @Travis, Unfortunately this must be done after the fact, not in real time.

Comment: Don't bother.  As soon as users identify that you're looking for similar addresses they'll create others.  You can get a million from mailinator.com (and the many aliases it supports).

Comment: I know this isn't the answer your looking for, but I was curious if you could also use their IP address to narrow down which entries to compare.  I would think that someone submitting multiple requests would probably do everything at the same time from the same machine (IP).

Comment: You need to be careful with things like Gmail.  The following addresses all go to the same mailbox:
somename@gmail.com  someNAME@gmail.com  some.n.a.m.e@gmail.com  somename+arbitrarytext@gmail.com

Comment: Agree with Sam, there's not much you can do about it.

I could register bla@gmail.com and ahahah@mailinator.com and your system won't get it.

Better to ban all the mailinator adresses (@mailinator.com + the other 10 or so domains that they provide...) and maybe the slopsbox adresses too (they provide a good 100 different domains so that's a bit longer)

Moreover, chances are that you'll be blocking legitimate users, e.g. the -not so bizarre- scenario where john1945@gmail.com is really a different person from john1980@gmail.com 

Even if you pass the list to a human afterwards how can he tell?

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the input, really, but I'm not looking for a 100% solution. We're just trying to catch the idiots who simply modify their email addresses by a single letter or number to gain multiple entries in the system. If someone wants to go through the time to actually create a number of significantly varied email addresses, more power to them.

Comment: What does the profiler tell you is the bottleneck?

Comment: @Eric, the levenshtein algorithm, which isn't surprising since that's really the only think this code is doing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**You could start by applying some prioritization to which emails to compare to one another.**

A key reason for the performance limitations is the O(n<sup>2</sup>) performance of comparing each address to every other email address. **Prioritization is the key to improving performance of this kind of search algorithm.**

For instance, you could bucket all emails that have a similar length (+/- some amount) and compare that subset first. You could also strip all special charaters (numbers, symbols) from emails and find those that are identical after that reduction.

You may also want to create a trie from the data rather than processing it line by line, and use that to find all emails that share a common set of suffixes/prefixes and drive your comparison logic from that reduction. From the examples you provided, it looks like you are looking for addresses where a part of one address could appear as a substring within another. [Tries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) (and [suffix trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree)) are an efficient data structure for performing these types of searches.

Another possible way to optimize this algorithm would be to use the date when the email account is created (assuming you know it). If duplicate emails are created they would likely be created within a short period of time of one another - this may help you reduce the number of comparisons to perform when looking for duplicates.

Answer (score 6):

Well you can make some optimizations, assuming that the Levenshtein difference is your bottleneck.

1) With a Levenshtein distance of 2, the emails are going to be within 2 characters length of one another, so don't bother to do the distance calculations unless `abs(length(email1)-length(email2))` <= 2

2) Again, with a distance of 2, there are not going to be more than 2 characters different, so you can make HashSets of the characters in the emails, and take the length of the union minus the length of the intersection of the two.  (I believe this is a SymmetricExceptWith)  If the result is > 2, skip to the next comparison.

OR

Code your own Levenshtein distance algorithm.  If you are only interested in lengths < k, you can optimize the run time.  See "Possible Improvements" on the Wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a few optimizations:

1) Keep a list of known frauds and compare to that first. After you get going in your algorithm, you might be able hit against this list faster than you hit the main list.

2) Sort the list first. It won't take too long (in comparison) and will increase the chance of matching the front of the string first. Have it sort by domain name first, then by username. Perhaps put each domain in its own bucket, then sort and also compare against that domain.

3) Consider stripping the domain in general. spammer3@gmail.com and spammer3@hotmail.com will never trigger your flag.

Comment: I'm actually already doing 1 & 2. 3 seems like more of a accuracy consideration than performance.

Comment: You are doing `toLower` very often as well. Consider doing `toLower` to the entire array before you start so you're not doing it every time.

Answer (score 1):

If you can define a suitable mapping to some k-dimensional space, and a suitable norm on that space, this reduces to the [All Nearest Neighbours Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search#All_nearest_neighbors) which can be solved in O(n log n) time.

Finding such a mapping, however, might be difficult. Maybe someone will take this partial answer and run with it.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, you should consider the semantics of email addresses as well, in terms of:

1. Gmail treats `user.name` and `username` as being the same, so both are valid email addresses belonging to the same user. Other services may do this as well. [LBushkin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812280/best-way-to-detect-similar-email-addresses/2812319#2812319)'s suggestion to strip special characters would help here.
2. [Sub-adrressing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-mail_address#Sub-addressing) can potentially trip your filter if users wise up to it. You'd want to drop the sub-address data before comparison.

Comment: I would say (using gmail as my example as well) parse the address or a + sign and strip everything from the + up to the @, then strip .'s, then pull all duplicates. Obviously you can't work backwards from this, so it's going to turn into a tuple where the first is a unique key, the second the original, the third the modified, then work with the list of the third ordinal of the tuple. Idk, that's how I would approach it, but based on potential sub-addressing schemes per available provider. ~~ Of course, users on their own domain could pretty easily spawn whatever address they want, so...

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the full data set to see if there is other commonality between accounts that have spoofed emails.

i don't know what your application does, but if there are other key points, then use those to filter down what addresses you are going to compare.

Answer (score 0):

Sort everything into a hashtable first.  The key should be the domain name of the email; "gmail.com".  Strip out special characters from the values, as was mentioned above.

Then check all the gmail.com's against one another.  That should be *much* faster.  Do not compare things that are more than 3 characters different in length.

As a second step, check all the keys against one another, and develop groupings there.  (gmail.com == googlemail.com, for example.)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with others comments about comparing email addresses not being to helpful, since users could just aswell create fraudulent disimilar looking addresses.

I think a better to come with other solutions, such as limiting the amount of emails you can write down per hour/day, or the time between those addresses being received by you and being sent to the users. Basically, work it out in a way where it is comfortable to send to send a few invites per day, but a PITA to send out many. I guess most users would forget/give up to do it if they had to do it through out a relatively long period of time in order to get their freebies.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any way you can do a check on the IP address of the person creating the email.  That would be a simple way to determine, or at least give you added information about whether the different email addresses have come from the same person.